# How to check if a date Object equals yesterday?

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-time

Right now I am using this code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1, 12, 0, 0); //Sets Calendar to "yeserday, 12am"
if(sdf.format(getDateFromLine(line)).equals(sdf.format(cal.getTime())))                         //getDateFromLine() returns a Date Object that is always at 12pm
{...CODE
```

There's got to be a smoother way to check if the date returned by getdateFromLine() is yesterday's date. Only the date matters, not the time. That's why I used SimpleDateFormat.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // today
c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1); // yesterday

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(getDateFromLine(line)); // your date

if (c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
  && c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
```

This will also work for dates like 1st of January.

Comment: Why does this work for the 1st of January? Won't the year be different for December 31?

Comment: It works because Calendar.add changes the timestamp of the date by an offset computed from the type of the field and the amount inputted. So no matter the original date, it only uses the timestamp (milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970) and computes the new date based on that plus/minus the difference computed for the input. This in effect will change the year as well, even though the field is DAY_OF_YEAR.

Comment: anyone seeing this thread should refer to @Przemek's answer, which uses `java.time`, which should be used in preference to joda-time, `java.util.Date`, and `java.util.Calendar`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33893147/1322243

Answer (score 25):

## java.time

Using `java.time` framework built into Java 8

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); //2015-11-24
LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1); //2015-11-23

yesterday.equals(now); //false
yesterday.equals(yesterday); //true
```

Official Oracle `LocalDate` [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) states

> The equals method should be used for comparisons.

If you're working with objects such as [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), or [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), you may convert to [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate(); # 2015-11-24
```

Comment: I suggest always passing the optional [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to [`LocalDate.now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can change at any moment even during runtime. Like this: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`

Answer (score 14):

I agree with Ash Kim that the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is the way to go if you want to preserve your sanity.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public static boolean dayIsYesterday(DateTime day) {
    DateTime yesterday = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusDays(1);
    DateTime inputDay = day.withTimeAtStartOfDay();

    return inputDay.isEqual(yesterday);
}
```

In this example, if the DateTime `day` is from yesterday then `dayIsYesterday(day)` will return `true`.

Comment: The midnight-related classes and methods in Joda-Time were based on a flawed idea. They are now deprecated as of Joda-Time 2.3. Instead use the method [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()).

Comment: Also, you should generally [specify time zone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) rather than rely on JVM's default as that is critical to determining "today" and "yesterday".

Comment: now = "1/07/2016". previous = "12/06/1980". Your previousFromYesteray will be set to true, while the topic starter asked about how you can check if a date is "yesterday".

Comment: @Dogcat good point. Edited. 2011 me has some explaining to do.

Comment: @plowman there's even more room for improvement :) You use DateTime which makes sense but for this particular task LocalDate from JodaTime will do just perfect.

Answer (score 9):

## Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006423/642706) is technically correct but less than optimal. The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (in Java 8).

## Time Zone

Time zone is critical in date-time work. If you ignore the issue, the JVM's default time zone will be applied. A better practice is to always specify rather than rely on default. Even when you want the default, explicitly call `getDefault`.

The beginning of the day is defined by the time zone. A new day dawns earlier in Berlin than in Montréal. So the definition of "today" and "yesterday" requires a time zone.

## Joda-Time

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" );
DateTime today = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

One way to determine yesterday is by converting to LocalDate objects. Another way, shown here, is to represent "yesterday" as a span of time. We define that span as going from the first moment of yesterday up to *but not including* the first moment of today. This approach is called "half-open" where the beginning is **inclusive** and the ending is **exclusive**.

Subtract a day to get to yesterday (or day before).

```
DateTime yesterdayStartOfDay = today.minusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
Interval yesterdayInterval = new Interval( yesterdayStartOfDay, today.withTimeAtStartOfDay() );
```

Convert your target java.util.Date object to a Joda-Time DateTime object. Apply a time zone to that new object, rather than rely on applying JVM's default time zone. Technically the time zone here in this case is irrelevant, but including a time zone is a good habit.

```
DateTime target = new DateTime( myJUDate, timeZone );
```

Test if the target lands within the interval of yesterday.

```
boolean isYesterday = yesterdayInterval.contains( target );
```

Obviously this approach with half-open span of time works with more than just "yesterday", such as "this week", "last month", and so on.

**Updated:** The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. See the java.time solution in the [correct Answer by Przemek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33893147/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the calendar try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    String prevDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime() - DAY_IN_MILLIS);
    String currDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime());
    String nextDate = dateFormat.format(date.getTime() + DAY_IN_MILLIS);
    System.out.println("Previous date: " + prevDate);
    System.out.println("Current date: " + currDate);
    System.out.println("Next date: " + nextDate);
  }
```

This should allow you to move forwards and backwards along the calendar

Then you can simply compare the getDateFromLine(line) to the prevDate value or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this roughly:

```
         Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
         Date d1 = new Date(/* control time */);
         c1.setTime(d1);

        //current date
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        int day1=c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        int day2=c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

       //day2==day1+1
```

Comment: Should also compare the year values as well.

Comment: oh yes i forgot about the year.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it a little confuse when I use this way to test this method

```
 Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 1, 1);
 now.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

 SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 System.out.println(format.format(now.getTime()));
```

my expect is to print **1999-12-31**,but the actual is **2001-1-31**
I guess Calendar.add() only deal with day in month.

But the actual error is the way I create the Calendar object.
In Calendar ,month start with **0**,the variable now's value is 2001-2-1, I was  so self-conceit as not to print it.when I found something was wrong.
correct way to create a Calendar is :

```
 Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar(2000, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
```

The Calendar was so weird to an ex C# programmer :(

Answer (score 1):

The [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006423/10819573) uses legacy `java.util` date-time API which was the correct thing to do in 2010 when the question was asked. In March 2014, `java.time` API supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, it is strongly recommended to use this modern date-time API.

### Ways to get yesterday's date:

There are three ways:

1. [`LocalDate#minusDays(long daysToSubtract)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-)
2. [`LocalDate#minus(long amountToSubtract, TemporalUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-): It has got some additional capabilities e.g. you can use it to decrement a local date by days, weeks, months, years etc.
3. [`LocalDate#minus(TemporalAmount amountToSubtract)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minus-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-): You can specify a `Period` (or any other type implementing the `TemporalAmount`) to subtract.

Once you have yesterday's date, you can use [`LocalDate#isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) to check if it is equal to the given local date.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note: Replace the default ZoneId with the required ZoneId e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(today);

        // Decrementing by one day
        LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
        System.out.println(yesterday);

        // Alternatively
        yesterday = today.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(yesterday);

        // or
        yesterday = today.minus(Period.ofDays(1));
        System.out.println(yesterday);

        // A sample LocalDate
        LocalDate givenDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 10, 20);

        // Check for equality
        System.out.println(givenDate.isEqual(yesterday));
        givenDate = yesterday;
        System.out.println(givenDate.isEqual(yesterday)); // true
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-13
2022-11-12
2022-11-12
2022-11-12
false
true
```

### How to switch from the legacy to the modern date-time API?

You can switch from the legacy to the modern date-time API using [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) on a java-util-date instance. Once you have an `Instant`, you can easily obtain other date-time types of `java.time` API. An `Instant` represents a moment in time and is independent of a time-zone i.e. it represents a date-time in UTC (often displayed as `Z` which stands for Zulu-time and has a `ZoneOffset` of `+00:00`).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
        System.out.println(odt);
        // Alternatively, using time-zone
        odt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(ldt);
        // Alternatively,
        ldt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-13T21:08:36.538Z
2022-11-14T02:38:36.538+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2022-11-14T02:38:36.538+05:30
2022-11-14T02:38:36.538+05:30
2022-11-14T02:38:36.538
2022-11-14T02:38:36.538
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to reuse these extension methods. They were very influenced by this post answers. Thanks to everyone, by the way!

```kotlin
fun Date.isSameDay(other: Date): Boolean {
    val thisCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val otherCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    thisCalendar.time = this
    otherCalendar.time = other
    return thisCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == otherCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            && thisCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == otherCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
}

fun Date.isYesterday(other: Date): Boolean {
    val yesterdayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    yesterdayCalendar.time = other
    yesterdayCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1)

    return yesterdayCalendar.time.isSameDay(this)
}
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Don't hate them. On Android, you have to deal with these terrible data-time classes until you support only Android 26 and above or depend on third-party libraries. Let's respect those poor old and deprecated classes. They are still useful.

Comment: Nope, no need at all for the terrible legacy classes. Gradle Plug-in 4 now provides a “API desugaring” feature to retroactively use a subset of the *java.time* classes with older Android. And if that does not do it for you, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* project adapted to Android in the *ThreeTenABP* library. See links at bottom of [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24213619/642706).

Comment: Yap, I was adding the ThreeTenABP library to the project when I realized I don't want to add another third party library just to make this comparison...

About the Gradle Plugin 4 API desugaring, maybe I try! But this piece of code passes the large amount of tests I wrote to check the feature so... maybe I don't. But perhaps in another project  Thanks a lot for the comment!