# Read in a txt file separating and storing variables (String , Double and int) for later use

Tags: java

Beginner java programmer , 
I am Looking for a way to read in a txt file (output from a till) while manipulating certain data that relates to the shift type, transaction type and cost to give me my desired result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example line in txt document:

"**CARD**","**05-07-2012** 10:32:42","Laminate A4",10,**10**,"**NIGHTSHIFT**",1486510814,False,130

So the relevant information I need is in **bold** the rest of the information in the text line is irrelevant.

Where I need to find the total **cost** of all **card** transactions made **yesterday** (05-07-2012) on **Nightshift**.

Heres where I have gotten so far, I have tried to split at night shift. Also thought about using an array as well and storing each value to its own variable but found this too difficult.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
public class Finder{

public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat formatter= 
  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  today.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
  String yesterday = formatter.format(today.getTime());
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("textdocument.log"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
String[] numstrs = sc.nextLine().split(yesterday + "\"NIGHTSHIFT\""); // split by "

for(int i = 0; i < numstrs.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(numstrs[i]);
    System.out.println();

}
}
}
}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

Nightshift Totals On 05-07-2012

Cash total $20

Card total $40

Eftpos total $20

I hope I have asked clearly.

Thanks

Comment: You can use CSV parser, or if there is no `,` inside the quotes, you can just split along `,` and obtain the data to put in template output.

Comment: Here Is my new program how does it look now? http://i1149.photobucket.com/albums/o596/seanludo/errors-1.png

Answer (score 1):

If the data will always maintain the same format, I would recommend you use a CSV parser, such as [Java CSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) to parse your file. Assuming that the file has a standard format, you should have no problems selecting the fields you want.

If you want to remove the quotes (`"`), you could use the `.replaceAll("\"","");` function to remove them (once that you have split the data and obtained the fields you want).

Lastly, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006150/java-how-to-check-if-a-date-object-equals-yesterday) previous SO post you can check if a date happens to be the date of yesterday:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // today
c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1); // yesterday

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(getDateFromLine(line)); // your date

if (c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
  && c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
     //Do your math here
}
```

EDIT: I will try to make this a little bit more clear:

I am assuming that all your lines have the same format, like so:
`"CARD","05-07-2012 10:32:42","Laminate A4",10,10,"NIGHTSHIFT",1486510814,False,130`. This basically means that data within the line will always maintain its order, so, for instance, `NIGHTSHIFT` will always be the 6th value in the line. The same applies to the other pieces of information.

Since the file you have is character separated, in this case, with a comma, you could use Open CSV to process that file.

After extracting the sections you need, you could, if you want, use the `.replaceAll` function to remove the quotation marks from the data you have extracted. You can then compare the strings you have (Apache's `StringUtils` class could be useful).

If the string is equal to `NIGHTSHIFT`, you can then proceed and check if the date was that of yesterday by using the code segment I attached yesterday. If the date matches, you can use Java CSV to extract the cost, translate it to a numerical value (since you are dealing with cost, I would recommend the `BigDecimal` class since it does not have rounding issues as opposed to `float` or `double`) and do whatever mathematical operation you need.

All this should in turn, give you what you are after.

Comment: Ok thanks what about an instance of nightshift though?, Also I am still not enteirly sure that after removing the "" I know exactly how to store the variables correctly ? I don't mind if they overwrite for each line of the text file as long as the totals are calculated correctly.

Comment: Also is 'line' just the variable I store the current line from the text file in?

Comment: @user1511032: I have modified my answer. I doubt I can put it in simpler terms that this. If you have any other queries pertaining to this question let me know.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I just can't believe how much work for a simple task can't I split by columns instead totalling the cost whenever coloum 1,2 and 6 equal cash yesterdays date and night shift or does a CSV parse have to be carried out ? , also I can't remove the ' " ' ' " ' from either side

Comment: @user1511032: Yes you can just use the `.split()` function, the CSV parsing framework is just more robust. If you do something like so: `String card = line.split(",")[0].replaceAll("\"","");`, you should be able to get the string value of `CARD`, which is what you are after. Also, please keep in mind my suggestion for using `BigDecimal` due to rounding errors.

Comment: Now I am really getting somewhere using the split replace all method you have just stated, I have managed to successfully separate the 4 needed columns for each line although I just have a couple more questions if thats ok.

Comment: From this example:
CARD
"05-07-201215:39:00"
NIGHTSHIFT
4

You can see I have not been able to separate only the date stamp from the time sucessfully I currently have,
String date = line.split(",")[1].replaceAll(" " , "");
which still gives me "05-07-201215:39:00" I just want 05-07-2012.

Furthermore how do I convert the String 'cost' to a Big Decimal for calculation later.

Many Thanks

Comment: Ok could I do date = date.substring(0, date.length() - 9); To get rid of the time stamp and BigDecimal cost = new BigDecimal(num); to turn the num into cost as a Big decimal?

Comment: @user1511032: You can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)) `BigDecimal` constructor which takes in a string as an argument which should do what you need. As for the whole date issue, I am glad that you have managed but a more commendable solution (assuming the date format stays the same) would be to use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to parse your string into a date.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this :

```
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("CARD(.*)NIGHTSHIFT");
    // Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("textdocument.log"));
    // while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    final String nextString = "\"CARD\",\"05-07-2012 10:32:42\",\"Laminate A4\",10,10,\"NIGHTSHIFT\",1486510814,False,130";
    final StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(p.matcher(
        nextString.replaceAll("\"", "")).replaceAll("$1"), ",");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        final StringTokenizer sTmp = new StringTokenizer(st.nextToken()
            .trim(), " |-");
        try {
            final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int day = Integer.valueOf(sTmp.nextToken());
            final int month = Integer.valueOf(sTmp.nextToken());
            final int year = Integer.valueOf(sTmp.nextToken());
            today.set(year, month, day);
            today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
            System.out
                .println(new Date(today.getTimeInMillis()).toString());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // I do not understand why catch is used
            System.out.println("Integer hangs, skipped line.");
            continue;
        }
        st.nextToken();
        st.nextToken();
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
    // }
```

Comment: Catch was just used encase the file was not found or for some reason the file was formatted differently which is obviously shouldn't be.

Comment: Here catch is needed for Integer.valueOf(..) : if the nextToken() is not an int, Integer.class throws an Exception.