# How to set a Java Date object's value to yesterday?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get yesterday's date using Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425236/get-yesterdays-date-using-date)

What is an elegant way set to a Java Date object's value to yesterday?

Comment: [The modern/current answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33893147/5772882).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean to go back 24 hours in time.

```
 Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
```

or to go back one day at the time same time (this can be 23 or 25 hours depending on daylight savings)

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

These are not exactly the same due to daylight saving.

Answer (score 19):

With [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
  LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate yesterday = today.minus(Period.days(1));

    System.out.printf("Today is : %s, Yesterday : %s", today.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"), yesterday.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: +1 for using JodaTime instead of Date.

Comment: Java 8  LocalDate is very similar: `LocalDate.now().minusDays( 1 )`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `Date` to a `Calendar` object and "roll" it back a single day. Something like this helper method take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212353/193906):

```
public static void addDays(Date d, int days)
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
    d.setTime(c.getTime().getTime());
}
```

For your specific case, just pass in `days` as `-1` and you should be done. Just make sure you take into consideration the timezone/locale if doing extensive date specific manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following example to set it to previous date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println("Today's date is " +dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));    
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  
System.out.println("Yesterday's date was "+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: That seems very complicated. Can you simplify the example?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I have just made more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try the follwing code:
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println("Today's date is "+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println("Yesterday's date was "+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: That looks similar to @UVM's answer. Can you try adding something his answer doesn't?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tested and it's worked fine

Comment: I know its fine, its just that its much the same as an earlier posting.

Answer (score 0):

As many people have already said use Calendar rather than date.

If you find you really want to use dates:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24);
cal.getTime();//returns a Date object

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
cal1.getTime();//returns a Date object
```

I hope this helps.
[tomred](http://www.tomred.net)