# get yesterday date from timestamp

Tags: java, datetime

I've got an object with a field `timestamp` with type `java.sql.Timestamp;`.
And I need to get objects with yesterday date from a collection.
How to get them?
I mean I need something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
   (if the items.get(i).date == yesterday_date)
       (get object)
}
```

Comment: use Calander for such requests

Comment: Duplicate: [How to check if a date Object equals yesterday?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3006150/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get yesterday's `Date` by following approach [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425236/get-yesterdays-date-using-date/11425259#11425259) by **Jiger Joshi**.

And by using `new Timestamp(java.util.Date)` you can get yesterday's timestamp, you should use `Timestamp#equals` to equaling two different timestamp.

```
if (items.get(i).date.equals(getYesterdaytimestamp())){
   ...
}
```

---

And there are something which you must consider while implementing this. `Calender#getTime` which returns `Date` object and date object contains date with time, so in that case your equaling date or timestamp must be exactly equals with yesterday's date and time.

If requirement is, it needs to equal just yesterday no not where time is not considerable fact. In that case you need to equals two timestamp after discarding time part.

```
if (equalsWithYesterday(items.get(i).date)){
    ...
}
...
public boolean equalsWithYesterday(Timestamp st){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // Time part has discarded
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Date yesterday = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); // get yesterday's Date without time part
    Date srcDate = new Date(st);
    Date srcDateWithoutTime =dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(srcDate));
    return yesterday.equals(srcDateWithoutTime ); // checks src date equals yesterday.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the timestamp object to date object like this:

```
Date date = new Date(items.get(i).getTime());
```

or you can simply use method [Timestamp#compareTo(Date o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29)

```
items.get(i).compareTo(yesterday_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are not interested to compare the time?

Simply use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to extract the day, month, year etc. from the date and simply compare it.

Use [Calendar#get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method to get the specific field from the date object.

---

How to subtract one day from the current date?

```
// get Calendar with current date
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// get yesterday's date
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

// get components of yesterday's date
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // 0 for January, 1 for Feb and so on
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

// get yesterday's date in milliseconds
long lMillis = cal.getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: What, you can't subtract a day from `Calendar` ;)