# query to get count of records till previous day

Tags: db2

I have a table "`empdata`" it contains fields `create date, last modified date, emp id`. In order to check count am running query "`select count(*) from empdata`". Now I need query where I have to get results till yesterday's date.

for example:

```
select count(*) from empdata
output: 23
```

`select count(*) from empdate` ( I need condition here for yesterday's date)

```
output:20
```

**Note:** **I need to use this query in java program so I cannot give yesterday's date in query. Java program will be running daily so date gets* changed daily.*

Comment: Just one database at a time or asking for a generic SQL solution would be best here. Which system are you running on? What's the column indicating the date?

Comment: useful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425236/get-yesterdays-date-using-date

Comment: createdate is column indicating. am running in db2

Comment: Then why on earth did you tag the question with mysql and ms sql tags in the 1st place? And why did you not remove them once your attention was called to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use this query to get the results, te condition you've asked should be

**where create_date < current_date()**

```
select count(*) from empdata where create_date<current_date()
```

You have mentioned that you want to run this program in java, Try jdbc

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/

**edit:**

use **CURRENT DATE** instead of current_date() in the above query for db2

Comment: when am running "select count(*) FROM empdata where createdate<current_date();" am getting error 
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "CURRENT_DATE" of type "FUNCTION" having 
compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: what is your db server, and version....?

Comment: You must be using DB2, there is no current_date() function in db2, use CURRENT DATE instead of that it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrews. It's working now