# How to get yesterday instance from Calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have an android app who manipulates dates via java.util.Calendar

When I want to use today's date, I use :

```
 Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

I want to know how to manipulate yesterday's date, I've tried multiple syntax but nothing worked, I was thinking about something like

> yesterday = today - 24(UNITS.HOURS)

but that's not correct !

Comment: So you just took a wild guess of what you could do instead of doing research? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and poorly designed `Calendar` and `Date`, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. `LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone).minusDays(1)`.

Comment: There’s [a good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33893147/5772882) (it does a little more than you asked for, just take the part that you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

using this code you will get yesterday date always.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1));
Date yesterDayDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Instead of "(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1)", only -1 can be written because getInstance method already has returned current date.

Comment: @SerkanYıldırım nope. first try it and then tell.

Comment: @SerkanYıldırım it will return only the day of month, while the whole date is required.